# Migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following blogger tutorial from jumpstartlab.com and I have problem..

This is error message in console which I get when I try to run `rake db:migrate`:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table tags already exists: CREATE TABLE "tags" 
("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255),
"created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) /home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.1.3/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize
```

How I can delete table `tags`? Should I just delete migration file?

This is schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150506111021) do

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "author_name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"

  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["article_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_article_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

This is `...create_tags.rb` migration file:

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is `...create_taggings.rb` migration file:

```
class CreateTaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :taggings do |t|
      t.references :tag, index: true
      t.references :article, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If you need any other file, I will update my question. Thanks!!

Comment: try `rake db:drop:all` and then try `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rake db:migrate` command is trying to create a table that already exists in your database.
There will be a `create_tags` migration file which has already been executed earlier.
That's why, as `tags` table is already created, so it's giving the error.

You can drop the whole database by

```
rake db:drop
```

then create a new databse

```
rake db:create
```

and then run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

or

generate a migration file by this command

```
rails g migration DropTags
```

then edit the code as this

```
class DropTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
      drop_table :tags    
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked.. But do you maybe know what was issue? Why this happened?